# DayMatchQ Alternative day name specification

Tags: date-and-time

Not clear from `DayMatchQ` [doc page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatchQ.html) but doesn't seem to work for say alternatives the way `MatchQ` does, eg

`DayRange[Today,DayPlus[Today,30]] // Select[DayMatchQ[#,Monday | Wednesday | Friday]]`

Returns `{}` as opposed to say matching `Monday` only.  Is there a different syntax or  workaround?

Don't tell me need to OR a list of `DayMatchQ`, ie WL diminishing orthogonality

Comment: DayMatchQ strictly takes only the following day types:  All (default), "Weekday", "Weekend", Monday through Sunday, "EndOfMonth", "BeginningOfMonth", "BusinessDay", and "Holiday". No alterrnatives allowed.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that DayMatchQ is more complicated than just matching a form. One workaround would be to use DayName:

```
Select[
  DayRange[Today, DayPlus[Today, 30]], 
  MemberQ[{Monday, Wednesday, Friday}, DayName[#]] &]
```

Answer (score 2):

If we assume our data is store in `data` variable:

```
data = DayRange[Today, DayPlus[Today, 30]];
```

1. We have [`DateSelect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateSelect.html) for date operations:

```
DateSelect[data, MatchQ[#DayName, Monday | Wednesday | Friday] &]
```

2. If you combine the `Listable` feature (not mentioned in `Attributes`) of `DayName` and `Pick`, you can get a faster alternative (almost **3 times** faster + using 4 times less memory):

```
Pick[data, DayName@data, Monday | Wednesday | Friday]
```

3. If you really care about performance, you can use numeric calculation instead which is around **30 times** faster than the previous version while consuming 1/3 of its memory:

```
Pick[data, Mod[IntegerPart[(AbsoluteTime /@ data)/86400.], 7], 0 | 2 | 4]
```

Of course all the outputs are the same. The timing was measured with `RepeatedTiming` on your sample data.